# Convert netcdf "land" variable to latitude and longitude with Python

Tags: python, grid, scipy, netcdf

I have a global meteorological dataset and I want to access the data for a certain grid (lat,lon). However, the data is compressed, i.e. the parameters of interest do not have the dimensions (lat, lon), but "land". "land" is a 1D array of integers.

I imported the file in python using

`import scipy.io.netcdf as netcdf`

`path = '/path/.../ncfile.nc'`

`ncfile = netcdf.netcdf_file(path,'r')`

Then I checked what variables there were and found that, e.g. the "Rainf" variable has the dimensions (tstep, land). I researched this on the internet and found the file landmask_gswp.nc (http://dods.ipsl.jussieu.fr/gswp/Fixed/landmask_gswp.nc), which is supposed to contain the information I need, that is, how to extract the information (lat, lon) from "land".
This file contains the variables nav_lat, nav_lon and landmask. nav_lat and nav_lon relate, to my understanding, the coordinate variables x and y to latitude and longitude. "landmask" is a 2D array and contains the information ocean = 0 or land = 1.
Indeed, the number of landpoints agrees with the length of my "land" 1D array. However, I cannot figure out how to extract the (lat, lon) information from it. Any help would be much appreciated.

I hope I made my problem somewhat understandable; I am not experienced with programming and/or using netcdf, so I hope that you can help out! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Some others might find this helpful, so here's the answer to the problem. A friend figured it out for me.
"land" is the index of the flattened array nav_lat, nav_lon, i.e. the first entry of "land" corresponds to the latitude: lat.flat[land[0]] and lon.flat[land[0]].

Comment: Ah gotchya now.  You can also use numpy [reshape](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html) to convert that flattened 1D array to 2D to match the lat/lon arrays.

Answer (score 0):

You can extract variables from `ncfile` using

```
lat = ncfile.variables['nav_lat'][:,:]
lon = ncfile.variables['nav_lon'][:,:]
```

This will create 2D numpy arrays `lat` and `lon`.

Comment: Hi and thanks for your answer. I think I might not have formulated my problem properly. I know how to get lat and lon if there are variables named nav_lat and nav_lon. My problem is that in my original netcdf file, there are no variables lat and lon, but only a variable "land", which is 1D. My question is: How do I extract the information (lat, lon) from the 1D array "land"?