# netCDF grid file: Extracting information from 1D array using 2D values

Tags: python, python-3.x, maps, netcdf

I am trying to work in Python 3 with topography/bathymetry-information (basically a grid containing x [longitude in decimal degrees], y [latitude in decimal degrees] and z [meter]).

The grid file has the extension .nc and is therefore a netCDF-file. Normally I would use it in mapping tools like Generic Mapping Tools and don't have to bother with how a netCDF file works, but I need to extract specific information in a Python script. Right now this is only limiting the dataset to certain longitude/latitude ranges.

However, right now I am a bit lost on how to get to the z-information for specific x and y values. Here's what I know about the data so far

```
import netCDF4

#----------------------
# Load netCDF file
#----------------------
bathymetry_file = 'C:/Users/te279/Matlab/data/gebco_08.nc'
fh = netCDF4.Dataset(bathymetry_file, mode='r')

#----------------------
# Getting information about the file
#----------------------
print(fh.file_format)
```

> NETCDF3_CLASSIC

```
print(fh)
```

> root group (NETCDF3_CLASSIC data model, file format NETCDF3):
>       title: GEBCO_08 Grid
>       source: 20100927
>       dimensions(sizes): side(2), xysize(933120000)
>       variables(dimensions): float64 x_range(side), float64 y_range(side), int16 z_range(side), float64 spacing(side), int32 dimension(side), int16 z(xysize)
>       groups:

```
print(fh.dimensions.keys())
```

> odict_keys(['side', 'xysize'])

```
print(fh.dimensions['side'])
```

> : name = 'side', size = 2

```
print(fh.dimensions['xysize'])
```

> : name = 'xysize', size = 933120000

```
#----------------------
# Variables
#----------------------
print(fh.variables.keys()) # returns all available variable keys
```

> odict_keys(['x_range', 'y_range', 'z_range', 'spacing', 'dimension', 'z'])

```
xrange = fh.variables['x_range'][:] 
print(xrange)
```

> [-180.  180.] # contains the values -180 to 180 for the longitude of the whole world

```
yrange = fh.variables['y_range'][:]
print(yrange)
```

> [-90.  90.] # contains the values -90 to 90 for the latitude of the whole world

```
zrange = fh.variables['z_range'][:]
```

> [-10977   8685] # contains the depths/topography range for the world

```
spacing = fh.variables['spacing'][:]
```

> [ 0.00833333  0.00833333] # spacing in both x and y. Equals the dimension, if multiplied with x and y range

```
dimension = fh.variables['dimension'][:]
```

> [43200 21600] # corresponding to the shape of z if it was the 2D array I would've hoped for (it's currently an 1D array of 9333120000 - which is 43200*21600)

```
z = fh.variables['z'][:] # currently an 1D array of the depth/topography/z information I want
fh.close
```

Based on this information I still don't know how to access z for specific x/y (longitude/latitude) values. I think basically I need to convert the 1D array of z into a 2D array corresponding to longitude/latitude values. I just have not a clue how to do that. I saw in some posts where people tried to convert a 1D into a 2D array, but I have no means to know in what corner of the world they start and how they progress.

I know there is a 3 year old [similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25750090/convert-netcdf-land-variable-to-latitude-and-longitude-with-python), however, I don't know how to find an analogue "index of the flattened array" for my problem - or how to exactly work with that. Can somebody help?

Answer (score 0):

You need to first read in all three of `z`'s dimensions (lat, lon, depth) and then extract values across each of those dimensions. Here are a few examnples.

```
# Read in all 3 dimensions [lat x lon x depth] 
z = fh.variables['z'][:,:,:] 

# Topography at a single lat/lon/depth (1 value):
z_1 = z[5,5,5]

# Topography at all depths for a single lat/lon (1D array):
z_2 = z[5,5,:] 

# Topography at all latitudes and longitudes for a single depth (2D array):
z_3 = z[:,:,5]
```

Note that the number you enter for lat/lon/depth is the *index* in that dimension, not an actual latitude, for instance. You'll need to determine the indices of the values you are looking for beforehand.

Comment: Unfortunately neither Lat nor Long could be read directly, the only variable with more than two values was z, the 1D array

Comment: I tried it just to be sure and I got the error "ValueError: slicing expression exceeds the number of dimensions of the variable".

Answer (score 0):

I just found the solution in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21889079/plot-gebco-data-in-python-basemap). Sorry that I didn't see that before. Here's what my code looks like now. Thanks to Dave (he answered his own question in the post above). The only thing I had to work on was that the dimensions have to stay integers.

```
import netCDF4
import numpy as np

#----------------------
# Load netCDF file
#----------------------
bathymetry_file = 'C:/Users/te279/Matlab/data/gebco_08.nc'
fh = netCDF4.Dataset(bathymetry_file, mode='r')

#----------------------
# Extract variables
#----------------------
xrange = fh.variables['x_range'][:] 
yrange = fh.variables['y_range'][:]
zz = fh.variables['z'][:] 
fh.close()

#----------------------
# Compute Lat/Lon
#----------------------
nx = (xrange[-1]-xrange[0])/spacing[0]   # num pts in x-dir
ny = (yrange[-1]-yrange[0])/spacing[1]   # num pts in y-dir
nx = nx.astype(np.integer)
ny = ny.astype(np.integer)
lon = np.linspace(xrange[0],xrange[-1],nx)
lat = np.linspace(yrange[0],yrange[-1],ny)

#----------------------
# Reshape the 1D to an 2D array
#----------------------
bathy = zz[:].reshape(ny, nx)
```

So, now when I look at the shape of both zz and bathy (following code), the former is a 1D array with a length of 933120000, the latter the 2D array with dimensions of 43200x21600.

```
print(zz.shape)
print(bathy.shape)
```

The next step is to use indices to access the bathymetry/topography data correctly, just as N1B4 described in his post